# Interpreting standard errors of parameter estimates in PGLS regression with phylolm

Tags: r, regression, phylogeny

I am using the phylolm function (in package phylolm) to conduct PGLS phylogenetic analysis and am having some trouble interpreting the model output.

I am running a phylolm model with a continuous (log transformed) response variable and one predictor variable which is a factor with two groups. When I change the reference group (from condition A to B) and rerun the same model, the estimates change accordingly but the standard errors do not seem to. The standard error for the new reference group remains very high - high enough that I don't see how the difference between groups can be significant (which the p value indicates they are). I was under the impression that phylolm standard errors can be interpreted in the same was as for ordinary linear regression - am I mistaken?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a binary variable, changing the reference category should only reverse the value of the beta estimate - should it not? This is what happens in your models.

It might help to think of the coefficient for the conditions as the different between the group means. The difference between the means will be the same size, but the sign will change depending if you are comparing condition A to condition B or condition B to condition A.

```
# Create a binary variable
x = sample(c(0,1), n, replace = TRUE)
# and create the opposite variable (ie. changing the reference level)
x.rev = +(!x)
# add some error to the model
error = runif(n)
# create the continuous response variablbe
y = 2 + 2 * x + error
df = data.frame(y, x)
# look at the group means between each condition
group_means = tapply(y, x, mean)
group_means[1] - group_means[2]
group_means[1] - group_means[2]
# compare those to the coefficients in the model
summary(lm(y ~ x))
summary(lm(y ~ x.rev))
```